# How to view structure of blade template in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

`.php` could view structure of html but `.blade.php` couldn't in PhpStorm.

How to use blade and view structure of html at the same time?

Comment: You can view the structure of a blade template with the shortcut `ctrl + F12`. For me it displays the used Blade directives, like `@section` and `@push`. But like you say, it does not display the HTML structure. Since we know it is possible and only the file extension messes things up, I am wondering if there is some PhpStorm setting for this that we overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment it's not possible -- only blade structure.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24524 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.